# How can I free my hashtable memory so that it passes a Valgrind check?

Tags: c, valgrind, cs50

I am having trouble passing my Valgrind check for pset5 in Harvard's CS50 course.  I believe it is a problem with my load or unload function not assigning or freeing both fields within the node struct.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Number of buckets in hash table
#define HASH_BUCKETS 10000

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Declare hash table
node *hashtable[HASH_BUCKETS];

// Hashes word to a number
int hash(const char *hash_word)
{
    // Hash function provided by delipity
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(hash_word); i < n; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ hash_word[i];
    }
    return hash % HASH_BUCKETS;

}

// Initialize word counter for dictionary size
int word_count = 0;

// Set all hash table heads to NULL initially
void null(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_BUCKETS; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // open dictionary file
    const char *infile = dictionary;
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // initialize buffer array to read into
    char wordbuffer[LENGTH + 1];

    // read into buffer array, 1 word at a time, until EOF is reached
    while (fscanf(inptr, "%s", wordbuffer) != EOF)
    {
        // allocate memory and return pointer to said memory
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // copy our word from our buffer array into our word field in our node
        strcpy(n -> word, wordbuffer);

        // pass our word into a hash function, returning a integer corresponding to our hash table
        int key = hash(n -> word);

        // initialize head of linked list to point at the proper bucket
        node *head = hashtable[key];

        // Add n to the front of the linked list
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            hashtable[key] = n;
            word_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            n -> next = hashtable[key];
            hashtable[key] = n;
            word_count++;
        };
    }
    fclose(inptr);
    return true;
}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // create copy of word to check
    int n = strlen(word);
    char word_copy[n + 1];

    // change the word to all lowercase to receive same hash_index as lowercase dictionary hash_index
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        word_copy[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    // add null terminator to end of string
    word_copy[n] = '\0';

    // hash the word copy
    int h = hash(word_copy);

    // initialize a navigator node to compare with the loaded dictionary
    node *nav = hashtable[h];

    // iterate through hash_table to check for the input word
    while (nav != NULL)
    {
        // check if strcasecmp returns 0 - exact match
        if (strcasecmp(nav -> word, word_copy) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // go to the next element in the linked list
        else
        {
            nav = nav -> next;
        }

    }
    // if the nav makes it through the list, then the input word is not there
    return false;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // Initialize head and track
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_BUCKETS; i++)
    {
        node *track = hashtable[i];
        node *tmp = NULL;

        // Iterate through the linked list
        while (track != NULL)
        {
            tmp = track;
            track = track -> next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        free(track);
    }
    return true;
}
```

My Valgrind spits out this:

```
==1735== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1735==    at 0x4013E9: unload (dictionary.c:155)
==1735==    by 0x400E59: main (speller.c:152)
==1735==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==1735==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1735==    by 0x4011BD: load (dictionary.c:67)
==1735==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
==1735== 
==1735== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1735==    at 0x4C30CF1: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1735==    by 0x40141F: unload (dictionary.c:161)
==1735==    by 0x400E59: main (speller.c:152)
==1735==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==1735==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1735==    by 0x4011BD: load (dictionary.c:67)
==1735==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
==1735== 
==1735== 
==1735== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1735==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1735==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 143,096 frees, 8,023,416 bytes allocated
==1735== 
==1735== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1735== 
==1735== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1735== ERROR SUMMARY: 20773 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I have tried to initialize the hashtable to point at NULL before loading :

```
void null(void)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < HASH_BUCKETS; i++)
         {
             hashtable[i] -> next = NULL
         }
}
```

but as this is a helper file & I am not allowed to edit the executable file "speller.c", im not sure how where I would call this.

speller.c :

```
// Implements a spell-checker

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Undefine any definitions
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// Default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// Prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./speller [DICTIONARY] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Structures for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // Benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // Determine dictionary to use
    char *dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // Load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Exit if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Try to open text
    char *text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(text, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // Prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Spell-check each word in text
    for (int c = fgetc(file); c != EOF; c = fgetc(file))
    {
        // Allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // Append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // Ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // Consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

                // Prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // Ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // Consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && isalnum(c));

            // Prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // We must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // Terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // Update counter
            words++;

            // Check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // Update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // Print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // Prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fclose(file);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // Close text
    fclose(file);

    // Determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // Abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // Report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
           time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // Success
    return 0;
}

// Returns number of seconds between b and a
double calculate(const struct rusage *b, const struct rusage *a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                 ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                  (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the `unload` function in your code? It seems to be what you need.

Comment: I'm voting to close because the code is incomplete and does not show how any of these functions are invoked. Please [edit] to include the full, compilable code that has the problem.

Comment: `unload()` loops over all buckets' elements in the array. But is it guaranteed that those will all have been initialised or assigned? If not, then some are uninitialised, and Valgrind is therefore correct. It looks to be a file-scope (global) variable, hence it should be zero-initialised, but we can't be 100% certain of that because the posted code is incomplete. For the same reason, you might've assigned a garbage value to one of the elements after, even if it was originally initialised properly. And so on, etc.

Comment: We don't know what's in `speller.c`. I agree with the others that you probably forget to call  `unload`. That last `free` in `unload` is actually redundant (but, I believe, harmless) - `track` is known to be NULL at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the `next` member of your `node` struct. There's conditions where it is not initialized.

Change your code to

```
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        hashtable[key] = n;
        word_count++;
        n -> next = NULL;  // Add this line

    }
    else
    {
        n -> next = hashtable[key];
        hashtable[key] = n;
        word_count++;
    }
```